# Incorrect Page numbers in Birt PDF

Tags: pdf, report, birt

I have created a report using Birt 3.7.2 The report behaves exactly how I want when using the web viewer and even when exporting to PDF from the web viewer. However When running the report direct to PDF all pages always show as page 1, causing conditional formatting to break.

Why would the page numbers work correctly to the viewer but not direct to PDF. Is there a workaround. The report is called from our application and attached to an email. As such we do need to be able to run it directly to PDF.

The page numbers are on the report body rather than in the Master Page.

I did see this was a bug in 2.6.1 but it was resolved in 2.6.2.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question: "The page numbers are on the report body rather than in the Master Page". I can't think of a simple way how you can 'know' the page number while staying within the body. Is there a reason why you can't move your page numbers to the master page?

Comment: I couldn't seem to get the report working properly when using the master page. The Report gets its background image and header / footer text from the data set. I couldn't find a way to have a dynamic image in the master page.

Comment: Even if you don't have anything else on it, the master page should still have space reserved at the footer.  Is there a reason you don't have just the page number on the master page footer?

Comment: The master page can use Data Sets just like the body. For example, create a DS "Master Page", create a Grid in the page header and bind it to this DS (the same with the page footer).

Comment: Indeed you can! It's very nifty. But I think the poster doesn't even need that for this problem (although it would probably be neater). If he/she keeps a blank master page with just the page numbers in the footer, it should work, as James said.

Comment: I will try binding a data set to the master page for the dynamic content in the header.

Comment: I have moved the page nos to the page master but now have issues with the height. My report is to generate customer documentation. The report has the following layout Address (varies 3-7 lines) like you have on a letter. A dynamic paragraph that needs to display on the 1st page. Then a grid of data. At the top of this grid on each page we should have the page number. As the dynamic paragraph varies in length it doesn't layout properly if the paragraph is -long. If it is short i end up with too much wight space. As far as i know its not possible to do dynamic heights on the page master.